# Why does chrome keep inserting the __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ class

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Almost every time I edit the css applied to an element in the Chrome dev tools, chrome inserts the **web-inspector-hide-shortcut** class which make the element not display. The whole reason I'm editing the css is to see what it looks like with the new style applied. I have to go to the HTML of the element and remove the class so I can see the changes.

How can I stop chrome from doing this automatically?

Comment: You must be hiding the element by e.g. typing `h` key when the Elements panel is focused.

Comment: Is there a way to change that. Every time I add the width or height or any other css setting that has an 'h' in it the element disappears. Can't it be set to ctrl+h so at least it will only happen when I intend it to?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome but I can't reproduce this behavior so maybe it's caused by some external factor like keyboard driver or a utility. You can file a report on https://crbug.com

Comment: I use Chrome dev tools ALL THE TIME. First time ever today I must have hit `'h'`. Do you have a cat and a bluetooth keyboard maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose if you literally can't help yourself hitting <kbd>h</kbd> you can just uncheck this checkbox once and you won't have to worry as long as that window is open.

[image]